# How can I web scrape a government website with python? I cannot properly do it, the table just cannot show

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape the data from this government website: https://www.itf.gov.hk/en/project-search/search-result/index.html?isAdvSearch=1&Programmes=TVP
However, after reading a lot about web scrapping, following Youtube video, I still can’t do it. Can someone please help?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.itf.gov.hk/en/project-search/project-profile/index.html?ReferenceNo=TVP/2122/22'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
soup 

table = soup.find('table',{'class':'colorTbl projDetailTbl'})
headers=[]
for i in table.find_all('th'):
    title = i.text.strip()
    headers.append(title)
 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers)
 
for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    data = row.find_all('td')
    row_data = [td.text.strip() for td in data]
    length = len(df)
    df.loc[length] = row_data
```

The table didn't show at all. The result is none. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The table is rendered through javascript, and the data returned through an api. You need to get the data from the source.

Once you have the `"Reference"`, you then can feed those into the api again to get the "linked" data. And finally merge them together.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests


tokenUrl = 'https://www.itf.gov.hk/API/Token/Get'
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }

token = requests.get(tokenUrl, headers=headers).text

url = 'https://www.itf.gov.hk/API/Project/Search'
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'verificationtoken': token}

# Get Full Tables
page = 1
rows = []
while True:
    payload = {
        'Page': '%s' %page,
        'Programmes[]': 'TVP'}
    
    jsonData = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload).json()
    
    rows += jsonData['Records']
    page += 1
    print(f"{len(rows)} of {jsonData['Total']}")
    if len(rows) == jsonData['Total']:
        print('Complete')
        break

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
references = list(df['Reference'])

# Use References to get "linked" data
refRows = []
for ref in references:
    print(ref)
    url = 'https://www.itf.gov.hk/API/Project/Get'
    payload = {
        'Reference':ref}

    jsonData = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload).json()
    
    TechnologicalSolutions = jsonData['TechnologicalSolutions'][0]
    row = jsonData
    row.update(TechnologicalSolutions)
    
    refRows.append(row)
    
refDf = pd.DataFrame(refRows)

# Merge together
df = df.merge(refDf, how='left', on = ['Reference'])
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
     Reference  ...       SCName
0  TVP/2122/22  ...      销售点管理系统
1  TVP/2120/22  ...      销售点管理系统
2  TVP/2107/22  ...     企业资源规划方案
3  TVP/2105/22  ...     企业资源规划方案
4  TVP/2103/22  ...     电子库存管理系统
5  TVP/2101/22  ...  文件管理及流动存取系统
6  TVP/2097/22  ...      销售点管理系统
7  TVP/2092/22  ...     企业资源规划方案
8  TVP/2086/22  ...      销售点管理系统
9  TVP/2085/22  ...     企业资源规划方案

[10 rows x 66 columns]
```

Comment: What if I want to open it in xlsx or googlesheet? I tried to open it in xlsx but openpyxl.utils.exceptions.IllegalCharacterError appears.

Comment: And some of the result are incorrect

Comment: The results are not incorrect. this is literally the data that renders into the table. I had no problem opening in excel. `df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)`

Comment: But the data I want is all 9 rows inside each link. With the code, it is only showing Project Reference, Project Title, Lead Applicant / Name of Company, Project Coordinator / Person-in-charge of Company (PIC), Fund Approved. It is still missing some of the data.

Comment: Ok. You never mentioned that at all in your question. In the future, you need to be explicitly clear as to what you are wanting as an output. Simply saying `" I still can’t do it."` gave me no indication of that.

Comment: Sorry but there is another error with the code. TechnologicalSolutions = jsonData['TechnologicalSolutions'][0] has IndexError: list index out of range. Does this happen to you too?

Comment: at what `ref` does that occur? It should be the last one printed on your console before you got the error

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the website, I see no such class `projDetailTbl`. However, you can use the following code to be able to process the data from the website.

```py
table = soup.find('table', class_='colorTbl')
```

or you can search on `id` if there happen to be more classes of the same name.

```py
table = soup.find('table', id='searchResultOutput')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that it could not be done as your site generates the table with javascript. The body of the html that you are getting in your soup is without the data:

```html
<body>
<div id="content"><script src="/filemanager/template/common/js/search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<h1 class="a_center">Project Profile</h1>
<div class="tableResponsive" id="projectProfile"> 
<table class="colorTbl projDetailTbl">
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
<div class="remarks" id="techAreaRemark" style="display: none;">* The primary technology area as indicated by the project coordinator is placed first.</div>
</div></div>
</body>
```

That is the soup (part of it) that you are getting with :

```py
url = 'https://www.itf.gov.hk/en/project-search/project-profile/index.html?ReferenceNo=TVP/2122/22'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
```

The content of the page is filled up afterwords with:

```html
<div> id="content"><script src="/filemanager/template/common/js/search.js" type="text/javascript"></script> ...
...
</div>
```

Your code is probably ok but the page you are scraping is not filled with data yet, when you put a request.
Maybe you could try to get it using Selenium.....
Regards...

Answer (score 0):

I used [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io) and [webdriver_manager](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager) to work with *javascript execution*

To install **selenium** run `pip install selenium` and to automatically load the drivers, install **webdriver_manager** `pip install webdriver-manager`

Here is my code *(worked for me)*:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager # automatic webdriver for Chrome browser (can change to your browser)

URL = 'https://www.itf.gov.hk/en/project-search/project-profile/index.html?ReferenceNo=TVP/2122/22'
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml; q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
}

# opening the page and get elements from the table
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(4) # falling asleep (4 sec) to accurately load the table on the site

# getting the name of the line and its content
data = {}
index_elem = 1
while True:
    # through the lines until we reach the non-existent
    try:
        columns_name = driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="projectProfile"]/table/tbody/tr[{index_elem}]/th').text
        columns_content = driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="projectProfile"]/table/tbody/tr[{index_elem}]/td').text
        data[columns_name] = [columns_content]
        index_elem += 1
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Project Reference  ...    Technological Solution(s)
0       TVP/2122/22  ...  Point-of-Sales (POS) System
```

Comment: But how do I loop through all items? This can only load one item.